# GIMP isn't running

Tags: windows-10, gimp

GIMP isn't running on my windows 10 computer. it was working before, and i used it to edit multiple pictures multiple times. but now, i run gimp-2.10.exe, and it shows the loading icon next to the cursor, and then just stops. no error, no window opens, it just stops. i tried multiple times, and nothing works. i tried running as administrator, i tried shortcuts, i made sure "read only" was unchecked, but **it will not run.** it doesn't appear in the task manager. computer is at 15% cpu, and there was nothing wrong before. i tried right clicking an image file and opening with gimp, i tried everything i could think of(nothing i could find on the internet provided anything useful). the only thing i can think of is to reinstall, but that would take a long time.

Comment: There is some suspected interference with Sophos Antivirus, for reasons only Sophos can know. Do you run that?

Answer (score 3):

- Start Gimp with a `--verbose` parameter (command prompt or editing the shortcut)s. In Windows this makes it open a side window with console messages that may tell you things.
- Locate your [Gimp profile](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/), and erase the `sessionrc` file in it (this is were Gimp keeps window positions, and would solve the case where somehow the saved position is off-screen (did you use two monitors recently)?
- erase (or better, rename if you have added things) the Gimp profile, Gimp will recreated a "fresh" one which hopefully will make it display its windows.

Re-installing Gimp is rarely useful, because this re-installation keeps the existing Gimp profile which is usually the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same issue. Eventually I have found [this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues/3633) thread outlining the problem. There seems to be strong evidence that the issue is caused by the interaction with Sophos antivirus. Currently a suggested *'solution'* is to downgrade to [Gimp 2.10.2](https://download.gimp.org/mirror/pub/gimp/v2.10/windows/) which is the most recent version where this issue does not occur.

EDIT (and a correction):
I have had to downgrade all the way to **2.10.0** in order for GIMP to work. The issue still occured exactly as described in 2.10.2.

Answer (score 1):

If this turns out to be caused by Sophos blocking the start-up of GIMP, then this can be fixed by getting the most current installer for GIMP 2.10.14: [gimp-2.10.14-setup-2.exe](https://download.gimp.org/mirror/pub/gimp/v2.10/windows/gimp-2.10.14-setup-2.exe)

What Sophos doesn't like isn't GIMP itself, but a specific and arguably erroneous behavior of a dependency of GEGL, namely OpenBLAS. The [actual code change](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/pull/2314) went there, and the installer linked before packages this updated dependency.